# Populating a UITableView with a Remote Plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, plist

I have a plist uploaded on a server. When I log the array with:

```
NSLog(@"My Array: %@", topModsArray);
```

It displays:

```
    "New item 0",
    {
    curVersion = "1.2.5";
    description = "This mod enables you to install other mods, does not modify the gameplay itself, helps other mods to.";
    maker = Risugami;
    mcVersion = "1.2.5";
    name = ModLoader;
    rating = 5;
    requires = Nothing;
},
"New item 1",
    {
    curVersion = "3.3.8.153";
    description = "This mod is like ModLoader, it allows other mods to be installed and work properly. This adds more capability for developers when making their mods.";
    maker = SpaceToad;
    mcVersion = "1.2.5";
    name = "Minecraft Forge";
    rating = 5;
    requires = ModLoader;
},
"New item 2",
    {
    curVersion = "1.2.5";
    description = "This mod gives capability for clients to use certain mods and for servers to be modded.";
    maker = Flan;
    mcVersion = "1.2.5";
    name = ModLoaderMP;
    rating = 5;
    requires = ModLoader;
},
"New item 3",
    {
    curVersion = "3.6.2";
    description = "This mod adds much more mobs to minecraft, making the game more fun and enjoyable. (Be warned it adds much more hostile mobs, and in the water)";
    maker = DrZhark;
    mcVersion = "1.2.5";
    name = "Mo' Creatures";
    rating = 5;
    requires = "ModLoader, Minecraft Forge, GUI API and CustomMobSpawner";
},
"New item 4",
    {
    curVersion = "3.1.5";
    description = "This mod makes minecraft more realistic with pipes, quarrys, machines, and much more. If you want your minecraft to be more realistic, this is a must have mod.";
    maker = "SirSengir (Now Opensource)";
    mcVersion = "1.2.5";
    name = Buildcraft;
    rating = 5;
    requires = "ModLoader and Minecraft Forge";
}
```

Which is what I want it to display, however when I try to add the name key to a UITableView with this:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[topModsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
```

My app crashes with SIGABRT:

```
2012-06-27 12:54:37.765 MinePedia[72019:f803] -[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6c8bad0
2012-06-27 12:54:37.766 MinePedia[72019:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6c8bad0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x13bd052 0x154ed0a 0x13beced 0x1323f00 0x1323ce2 0x3424 0xade0f 0xae589 0x99dfd 0xa8851 0x53301 0x13bee72 0x1d6792d 0x1d71827 0x1cf7fa7 0x1cf9ea6 0x1d8530c 0x25530 0x13919ce 0x1328670 0x12f44f6 0x12f3db4 0x12f3ccb 0x12a6879 0x12a693e 0x14a9b 0x2868 0x27c5)
terminate called throwing an exceptionsharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
(gdb)
```

Please help me

Comment: the exception means your [[topModsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]  is a NSString, not dictionary

Comment: Try logging some info to get clear info - NSLog(@"%@",[topModsArray objectAtIndex:0]); NSLog(@"%@",[[topModsArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"New item 0"]);

Comment: NSLog(@"%d",[topModsArray objectAtIndex:0].count); is this return 2..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see make one array in your .h and alloc it in view did load and and use that to show your table, make your array like this...

```
for(int i =0 ;i <topModsArray.count ; i++ ){
    id object = [topModsArray objectAtIndex:i];
if([object isKindOfClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]] || [object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){
     NSMutableDictionary  *dict = (NSMutableDictionary *)object;
     [yourArray addObject:dict];
 }
```

now return number of row is yourArray.count and in your cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
 NSMutableDictionary  *dict = [yourArray objectAtIndexPath:indexPath.row];
 cell.titleLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"name"];
```

use this may this help you

Comment: Might do but my `topModsArray` is a NSMutableArray

Comment: Right this kind of works, it displays the name key but on every other cell. The cell with nothing in it crashes the app but the other one pushes the next view :). How do I remove the cell with nothing in it

Comment: check how many row you are returning .. may be you are returning 
[topModsArray count].. this is the main error.. you should return only number of row how much you have dictionary in your array got my point?

Comment: you can check it correct and vote up if it is working fine .. :)

Comment: But when it asks for row == 0, `object` will not be a dictionary, so what goes into that cell?

Comment: By the looks of things.. Nothing but creates the cell :\ thats what i want to get rid of

Comment: Im not gonna vote it up yet because it doesnt fully do what i need it to

Comment: I want it to display all the contents of the plist, which it does. But It also creates an empty cell before each item in the plist, I dont want this. When the empty cell is clicked it crashes when the other one is clicked it pushes the new view

Comment: bro tell me one thing first you wanted to show only name of dictionary and now you are saying you you want to show everything .. too much confusing you are... :(

Comment: No... I want to show the name of EACH item in the dictionary. Without the blank cells being created in between each cell

Comment: can you please make it in iphone and please attach the screens shot what you want exactly ...

Comment: OK right... I have an array plist with at the moment 5 dictionaries inside it, each dictionary has 7 keys, one of the keys is "name", I want to display the "name" of each dictionary inside the tableview. The plist array is being put into `topModsArray`

Comment: have you implemented that code i have written just before??? man you were not trying and just asking question again and again .. before this i have wrote the same code what you wanted... :(

Comment: The code you put up there displays "New item 0" then "ModLoader" then "New item 1" etc... Every other line now says the name of each dictionary. Getting closer

Comment: I dont understand that... And i cant upload screenshots because i dont have enough reputation

Comment: `yourArray` is that an NSArray or NSMutableArray or what?

Comment: ha ha ha its NSMutableArray  .. :) declare it in your .h and alloc in .m in viewDidLoadMethod

Comment: That displays a tableview with empty cells. :/

Comment: can you please paste your total code and please post the total code with number of row in section method too ...

Comment: I can should I send it as a reply rather than a comment?

Comment: no in your code please ... not comment it will not readable make it in form of code...

Comment: Ill upload my project to Github and give you a link to that

Comment: That worked from ages ago, i found the problem... I had given a key to the dictionaries when the plist was a dictionary... I removed the keys now and it works fine thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your array is composed of alternating strings and dictionaries.  The object at offset zero is "New item 0", which doesn't have an `objectForKey:` method.  You need to select the items from your array that you actually want to display (...or index them using something like `indexPath.row * 2 + 1`).

Comment: but I'm using my plist to change labels and other things. How would I be able to get the "name" key from the dictionaries which are inside the plist array?

I only want to display the value in the "name" key in the table view

Comment: Like I said, either move the dictionaries into an array of their own or calculate the right offset. Untested, but probably: `cell.textLabel.text = [[topModsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row * 2 + 1] objectForKey:@"name"];`

Comment: What so change the `<dict>` to `<array>` in the XML of the plist? and then do the other bit?

Comment: No, I'm suggesting ways to deal with the data structure you already have.  If you do nothing except change the calculation for `objectAtIndex:`, is there still a problem?

Comment: Can you put `NSLog(@"Object: %@", [topModsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row * 2 + 1]);` in there to show what it's trying to read the `name` from?

Comment: When i do that. It crashes as well... Same crash